# Advantages of LINQ AsParallel.Select(SynchronousAction) versus Task.Run(SynchronousAction)

Tags: multithreading, linq, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

This question is about how to treat a third-party, synchronous file-reading method in an async/await or Task.Run() way. I have a list of 50+ incoming pathnames that I treat with `.AsParallel` to use more threads. BUT all the threads in the `AsParallel` statement could conceivably block and wait for a short time while `PathReadAndProcessOne(path)` does its synchronous work. Is that something I should worry about?

Some thread - either my thread or a thread pool thread - has to run and wait for the third-party file processor to complete. My calling thread doesn't have anything else to do but wait for the pathnames to be processed, so I am not sure that it matters if I use async or not to free up my calling thread.

The LINQ+synchronous code and the following Task.Run+asynchronous code both take about the same amount of time to run.

Is there a conceptual or future advantage to writing the code one way or the other?

```
// the LINQ+synchronous version - only one line of code
var nestedActions = paths.AsParallel().Select(PathReadAndProcessOne).ToList();


// The Task.Run() async version - ASYNC ALL THE WAY DOWN
// 
// loop over all paths and kick off a Task.Run for each one.
var allTasks = new List<Task<List<ActionItem>>>();
foreach (var path in paths) {
  var t1 = Task.Run(() => PathReadAndProcessOne(path));
  allTasks.Add(t1);
}

// after all tasks are started in the loop, await them all outside the loop
try {
  Task.WaitAll();
}
catch {
  return false;
}

// pull out the results and aggregate them
var nestedActions = new List<ActionItem>();
foreach (var t in allTasks) {
  nestedActions.AddRange(t.Result);
}
```

Comment: Option 3 is better - Dataflow or Channels. PLINQ/Parallel.For are meant for in-memory data parallelism, not asynchronous operations. They split the input data into partitions and use one worker per partition to minimize synchronization costs. That's not the case here. You can use a Dataflow pipeline to process file data in multiple steps, each running on its own "worker", eg crawling folders, parsing files, importing them into a database. You can adjust the number of workers per step to eg increase concurrent parsers.

Comment: In such cases you want to *limit* how many files are processed at a time. You can't process 50 files concurrently on a 4-core machine. Some tasks will have to wait, taking up buffers and RAM. You may end up with 50 files loaded in RAM but only 4 threads actively processing them

Comment: Thank you. I will have to look up Dataflow and Channels - I have never heard of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I recommend using `Parallel` or PLINQ (`AsParallel`) when you have more than a handful of tasks. `Task.Run` is one abstraction level lower, queueing a task onto the thread pool. `Parallel` and PLINQ have partitioning logic that schedules the work onto a set of tasks, and those tasks are the ones scheduled onto the thread pool. So especially for large workloads, I recommend `Parallel` / PLINQ for that reason. And between `Parallel` and PLINQ, PLINQ is easier to use if your operations have results, which yours do.

> My calling thread doesn't have anything else to do but wait for the pathnames to be processed, so I am not sure that it matters if I use async or not to free up my calling thread.

No, it doesn't matter in that case. If you do end up consuming this in a place where asynchrony matters (i.e., from a GUI thread), then you can wrap the parallel code within a single `Task.Run`.

Comment: Great answer - thank you! (haha, it's like you've done this before... I have just discovered all your work and am reading madly to understand everything!)